# command substitution doesn't work with echo in makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, scripting, gnu-make

Here's a simple command that works fine in my bash shell:

```
echo "Created at: $(date)" >> README.md
```

It appends `Created at: Wed Jan 24 10:04:48 STD 2018` to README.md.

However, ii I include the same command in my makefile, the behavior is different.

makefile:

```
README.md:
    echo "Created at: $(date)" >> README.md
```

Running `make README.md` will treat the command substitution as an empty string like this:

```
echo "Created at: " >> README.md
```

What's appended to README.md is `Created at:`.

How do I get command substitution to output properly with echo in a makefile?

Comment: This question is definitely _NOT_ a duplicate of the linked answer.  I'm sure there are lots and lots and lots of answers in SO for this question, but that one is not one.

Comment: I added a duplicate link which is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the shell that Make invokes to receive the following:

```
echo "Created at: $(date)" >> README.md
```

Then, you need to escape the `$` with another `$` inside the rule:

```
README.md:
    echo "Created at: $$(date)" >> README.md
```

Otherwise, the Make's variable `date` is expanded and that will be what `echo` gets as argument, since `$(date)` in a makefile expands the variable `date`.

---

#### Out of intererst

Note that, if the Make's variable `date` is defined as below, it will however work as expected without quoting the `$` in the rule:

```
date = $$(date)

README.md:
    echo "Created at: $(date)" >> README.md
```

The reason is that the variable `date` (used in the rule's recipe) will be expanded by Make to `$(date)` and that will be passed to the shell.